# Limitar numero de caracteres a mostrar en un p

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Se puede truncar un párrafo, y sólo dejar un determinado número de carácteres?
Estoy haciendo un blog y quiero que en la vista solo se vea un poco del contenido real, es decir, que se trunque.

Por ejemplo, para el texto:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Quiero que muestre:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book...

Creo que se hace con `Javascript` o con `JQuery`

Tengo este código:

```html
 <div class="card">
      <div class="image">
       <img src="images/<?php echo $row['articlePic']; ?>" alt="" width="300px" height="150px">
      </div>
      <div class="separator">
       
      </div>
     <div class="title">
      <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
     </div>
<!------Parrafo a truncar------------->
     <div class="content">
      <p><?php echo $content; ?>
    </p>
     </div>
     <div class="readmorebutton">
      <p>Ver más   &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: por favor, añade algo de código que ya tengas para que podamos ayudarte. Lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Si no vemos que hayas hecho nada, consideraremos que son deberes: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ya está :)
Estoy trabajando con PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estuve investigando, y esto es lo mejor que consegui conforme a lo que quieres

```css
.module {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module p {
  margin: 0;
}

.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="module line-clamp">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

En **-webkit-line-clamp** indicas el maximo de lineas que quieres, y puedes ajustar el largo del texto como gustes

Comment: Si he intentado con CSS, específicamente con ese, pero solo trunca una línea hasta donde termina la pantalla o bien, la caja, pero no hace más que eso, ¿Se pueden truncar mas de una línea?

Comment: a qué te refieres con truncar más de una linea?

Comment: Lo mismo pregunto

Comment: Es decir algo así:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sollicitudin quam fermentum, euismod pellentesque venenatis in arcu sed lacus magna rhoncus, consequat scelerisque vulputate augue auctor aptent mollis parturient condimentum.

A esto:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sollicitudin quam fermentum, euismod pellentesque venenatis in arcu sed lacus magna rhoncus, consequat...

Comment: Edite la respuesta

Comment: No use ni jquery ni JavaScript 

Comment: Jaja, eso es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias :,)

Comment: Si te funciono, podiras marcar la respuesta como correcta? C:

Comment: @PacManProgramador perdona, ya la he marcado xd

Comment: Entonces gracias c: